# Table creation fails with SqlAlchemy and Pylons

Tags: sqlite, sqlalchemy, pylons

I just upgraded to Pylons 1.0 and SqlAlchemy 0.6.5. What was a simple process of creating the DB schema no longer works.

I have a simple model:

```
Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_name = Column(String)

    def __init__(self, userName):
        self.userName = userName

    def __repr__(self):
       return "<User('%s')>" % (self.userName)
```

When I run

```
paster setup-app development.ini
```

the database file is created (sqlite3), but not the table, and no errors are returned.

Logging shows that the following lines in `websetup.py` do execute:

```
log.info("Creating schema...")
Base.metadata.create_all(bind = Session.bind, checkfirst = True)
log.info("Database successfully set up.")
```

What am I missing?

**Edit:** Further digging shows that the `Base.metadata.tables` dictionary is empty. So, why isn't the model reflected in the metadata?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the issue.

In `model.meta.py`, `Base = declarative_base()` was already performed. When I also added that statement to the `model.__init__.py`, it evidently creates a new instance without the metadata, so there were no tables to create.

I'm not clear on exactly why/how this works, so if anyone (Mike Bayer?) has details, I would love to know.